# Zipper like split-reveal animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm trying to make a split reveal animation in which it splits from the middle like a zipper and then shows the piece of text behind it completely. The concept idea can be explained something like this:
[image: zipper split reveal animation concept]

How do I achieve this animation? I have never made a custom animation before and I couldn't find one that works like this. Any help or hint is appreciated.